# Python math add each number together

Tags: c#, python, math

I did a math problem today and first attempted it in Python but after getting the wrong answer I used C#.  Basically I was to add up all the digits a long number (2^1000).  The sum of these digits was the answer.  Here is my python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

n = 2**1000
count = 0

while (n > 0):
    count += n % 10
    n = (int)(n/10)

print (count)
```

This script gives the result 1189.  Essentially I'm adding the last digit of the number to count, then removing it from the number and repeating the process.  Here is similar code in C#:

```
//Yes this string is the same output from 2^1000.  I had python write the string to file for me.
String str = "10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376";
Int32 answer = 0;
foreach (char c in str)
{
    answer += (Convert.ToInt32(c) - 48);
}

lblOutput.Text = answer.ToString();
```

C# gives the output: 1366 which is the correct answer.  I'm just curious as to why my python script gets the wrong answer.  Am I looking at the math in the wrong way?

Comment: Took me a second to figure out why your C-style cast `(int)(n/10)` wasn't a syntax error in Python.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this:

```
n = 2 ** 1000
count = 0

while n > 0:
    count += n % 10
    n //= 10

print(count)
```

---

Why your code goes wrong is because `(int)(n/10)` first converts `n` to a double, divides it by 10 and then truncates. Rounding errors are easily made in this process. In Python 3.X `//` is used for integer division.

---

Oh and finally, `(int)(n / 10)` is a very bad style, we don't use C-style casts in Python. You create a `int()` object, so you use `int(n / 10)`. This is error prone thanks to rounding errors, so use integer division instead: `n // 10`. And since we are doing `n = n // 10` we can write `n //= 10`.

Comment: Ah, I thought it must be some kind of truncating error but I wasn't sure why.  Thank you for explaining that it converts n to a double, which of course makes everything come into perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Use integer division.

```
n = n//10
```

By truncating after, you're losing very large fractions of 1 many times.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is really old but after reading over it I couldn't seem to understand the code and felt it was too hard for beginners to understand so I made a more 'noob-friendly' version using a list:

```
n=2**1000
thelist=list(map(int, str(n)))
counter=0
    for x in range(0,len(thelist)):
        counter+=thelist[x]
print(counter)
```

(i understand that this is less efficient btw)